# Grails: Integrating a Java Class

Tags: java, grails

I created a new Grails 3 application in IntelliJ IDE.

Here is the folder structure view from IntelliJ

[image: folder layout showing grails-app/ and src/ on the same level]

I then created two files, a controller with the following code,

```
package grailsjavatest
import test.JavaTest;
class JavaTestController {

    def index() {
        JavaTest jt = new JavaTest();
        render jt.someAction();
    }
}
```

and a Java files with the following code (in src/java/test/JavaTest.java),

```
package test;

class JavaTest{

    public String someAction()
    {
        return "<html> <body> <b> Hello From Java! </b> </body> </html>";
    }

}
```

However the following project errors with the following error,

```
[the java process command was removed as it is a bit long.]

| Running application...
startup failed:

/Users/user/IdeaProjects/GrailsJavaTest/grails-app/controllers/grailsjavatest/JavaTestController.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class test.JavaTest
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import test.JavaTest;
   ^

1 error



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I change the controller code to,

```
package grailsjavatest
class JavaTestController {

    def index() {
        render "<html> <body> <b> Hello From Java! </b> </body> </html>";
    }
}
```

the page renders as expect (but obviously not calling the java code).

**Edit**

Here is the file structure with the package created,

[image: JavaTest as a package and not a normal folder]

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaTest class is declared with default (package-private) modifier, so it is only visible to other classes declared in the same 'test' package.  Add the 'public' keyword to the start of the class definition (i.e. 'public class JavaTest{ yada, yada').

Alternatively follow the instructions given by Grails and "Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace." which should show you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer made little sense.

The problem is that 'test' is not a package folder (which contain a dot in IntelliJ), but a plain folder. But in order to add a package folder to your Java folder, your Java folder needs to be marked as a 'source folder' (which have a blue color). Right-click on the java folder, select 'Mark directory as' - 'Sources root'. The 'test' folder will now automatically be marked as a package folder (at least in IntelliJ 2016.1).

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, even with src marked as a Source Root and java a package the same error occurs.